# how can I display messages right to left in noty plugin

Tags: jquery, noty

I am using [noty](https://github.com/needim/noty)

how can I display messages right to left or change text align  in  'noty_message' class

thanks

Comment: edit the css of class `.noty_message` in stylesheet of this plugin and set the `align-text: right;`

Comment: i can not found any css file and this class is inline  added by noty

Comment: add this to css `.noty_message { text-align: right !important;}` this is ugly but will work

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by having a customized theme.

This is how to create your own theme for Noty:

1. First duplicate the default theme file which should be named `default.js` or `relax.js` or `bootstrap.js` under `noty/themes/`. Name the duplicate whatever you want and include the file in your HTML page.
2. Open the duplicate and do the following changes:

   - Search for "`defaultTheme`" and replace it with your own theme name. Do this on the whole code.
   - Search for `this.$message.css({fontSize: '11px', textAlign: 'left'});` and change "left" to "right".
3. On calling Noty in your main HTML page, specify the theme name you picked before like this:

   - `noty({text: 'Successful action', layout: 'topRight', type: 'success', theme: 'myThemeName'});`

---

**I have tested it for version `2.2.7` and it worked well.**